# Angularjs ng-Grid injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have used below code while using ngGrid.

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngGrid','ngRoute', 'ProductService']);
```

But it gave me following error.

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngGrid due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngGrid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

As per the suggestions in stack overflow then i changed my code as below.

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ui.grid','ngRoute', 'ProductService']);
```

But Still i got a different error.

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.grid due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.grid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="MyApp"> <head><title></title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="service.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

does any body have a clue on how to inject ngGrid and use it in angularjs application?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included your  `ng-grid-x.x.x.js` via the `<script>` tags? (x.x.x denotes the version)

Comment: You need to include the relative JS files from the module you installed.

Comment: It's working find with me using `var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngGrid','ngRoute', 'ProductService']);`. Do you have any other errors in your console?

Comment: Files were not loaded. Now it is sorted as @Michelem pointed out.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ng-grid JS file to your project:

```
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Michelm, Since this is SPA application i already added links in Index page (shell page).but still error comes..

Comment: Are you sure your ng-grid file is loaded? Check the web developer console.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2013. Do i need to add reference through nuget..

Comment: I don't know Visual Studio, you need to be sure you have the file `ng-grid-1.3.2.js`in your root/public folder you need to check if you can get the file by point your browser to it like `http://127.0.0.1/ng-grid-1.3.2.js`